# Galaxy Note 2 custom roms - Google Apps crashing

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-2, google-apps

I wanted to move from the default 4.2.1 kernel on my Galaxy Note 2 to customized ROMs, primarily to fix some issues with Bluetooth.

I first tried [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) 10.2 (Android 4.3) with `gapps-jb-20120726-signed.zip`. This worked for some time (and my BT issue was fixed) but since I have not done a full wipe prior to this first flash and recovered applications+data via Titanium Backup, the stability was not great.
I decided to start from scratch.

I reformatted the /sdcard in recovery mode (not only wipe), reinstalled CM 10.2 + gapps --> most of the apps now crash at startup (clock, keep, even the keyboard)

Since the issue seemed to come from gapps (the ROM alone works fine), I tried several gapps packages (reformatting every time). Same issue.

I then gave up on Android 4.3 and looked for a stable 4.2.2 version - [SlimROMs](http://www.slimroms.net/) seemed to be a good choice. I took the latest stable version, formatted, flashed and ... same issue (Google apps crashing). The account is set up but most of the apps crash sooner or later (Contacts for instance is not populated at all, even though the synchronization went through).

I would like at all cost to avoid reverting back to the original TW ROM. My questions are:

1. Could you recommend a stable custom ROM for a Galaxy Note 2?
2. What should I do to completely clean the phone so that there are strictly no leftovers (I format /sdcard, then wipe data/cache for good measure)?

Comment: Did you consider to wipe the Dalvik cache and, if that doesn't help, `/data`? If you played with several completely different ROMs, things might get messed up here. Wiping the SDCard doesn't help in those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to sort it out last night. Some of the steps are redundant.

1. boot in recovery mode
2. format all paths visible in boot & mount (possible redundancy here)
3. back to first level of menu, wipe factory clean, erase cache (redundant IMHO)
4. go to Advanced -> clean Dalvik cache
5. install [the latest nightly of CyanogenMod](http://get.cm/?device=n7100) (for lack of a more stable release)
6. install [their gapps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Gapps) (even if the Note 2 is not in the list of supported devices - if I read the table correctly)

I have done bits and pieces of the points before - but only all of them put together allowed me to have a working phone (like I said before, there were lots of leftovers from previous experiments).